# MySQL select from multiple table with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

- `ARTICOLE`
- `BAR`
- `BUCATARIE`
- `MAGAZIE`

mysql> `select * from ARTICOLE;`

```
| OID | ART      |  
|   1 | TEST     |
|   2 | TESTQ    |
|   3 | MYART    |
|   4 | MYARTBUC |
```

4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> `select * from BAR;`

```
| OID | ART   | CANT     |
|   1 | TEST  |  3.00000 |
|   2 | TESTQ |  1.00000 |
|   3 | MYART | 20.00000 |
```

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> `select * from BUCATARIE;`

```
| OID | ART      | CANT     |
|   1 | TEST     |  5.00000 |
|   2 | MYARTBUC | 10.00000 |
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> `select * from MAGAZIE;`
Empty set (0.00 sec)

the below query

mysql> `select a.ART,sum(bar.CANT),sum(buc.CANT),sum(mag.CANT) from ARTICOLE a,BUCATARIE buc,BAR bar,MAGAZIE mag where a.ART=bar.ART and a.ART=bar.ART and a.ART=mag.ART group by a.ART;`

return:

---

Empty set (0.00 sec)

### how must be query to return:

```
| ART | sum(bar.CANT) | sum(buc.CANT) | sum(mag.CANT) |
TEST  |  3.00000 | 5.00000 | NULL |
TESTQ |  1.00000 | NULL | NULL |
MYART | 20.00000 | NULL | NULL|
MYARTBUC | NULL | 10.00000 | NULL |
```

---

????

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Test Schema: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6efb2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of [**`LEFT JOIN`**](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php) to include results from other tables without filtering out records that don't match:

```
   select a.ART,sum(bar.CANT),sum(buc.CANT),sum(mag.CANT)
     from ARTICOLE a
left join BUCATARIE buc on buc.ART = a.ART
left join BAR bar on bar.ART = a.ART
left join MAGAZIE mag on mag.ART = a.ART
group by a.ART;
```

Sample results:

```
ART         SUM(BAR.CANT)   SUM(BUC.CANT)   SUM(MAG.CANT)
MYART       20      
MYARTBUC                    10  
TEST        3               5   
TESTQ       1
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6efb2/2